# What is an appropriate waiting time before resubmitting after I received positive feedback?

Tags: editing, submitting-work, feedback

Should I resubmit it through the regular submission channel or directly to the editor who replied (she included her contact info)?

I have revised the MS quite a bit this week based on their comments, but I don't want to rush sending it back to them.  Is there a proper waiting time to resubmit?

I kind of want the story to be fresh in their minds when they see it again.

Comment: Seems that I should email or snail mail directly to the editor asap. Not sure which I'll do yet (I may do both).

Comment: Go for it asap, and contact info is an invite to respond. Good luck!

Comment: Note that "rejection, with positive feedback" is still a rejection (an enthusiastic one, though, which is awesome!). Only resubmit if the editor actually asked you to.

Answer (score 5):

Inclusion of contact info is a show of preferred contact method. Reply directly to the editor and send it back as soon as it's done. Responding quickly will show that you are engaged and interested, and that you care about your work and their opinion.

Now, having said that, it *is* possible to send it back too early, but taking a day or two will look like you're responsive. Sending it back within a few hours will seem like you rushed through the revisions.